# Aggregate function error in Access update query using Max()

Tags: ms-access, aggregate-functions, max

```
UPDATE tblFiles INNER JOIN dbo_tblStats ON tblFiles.FileName = dbo_tblStats.Video SET tblFiles.CurRecord = Max([dbo_tblstats.stopframe])
WHERE (((tblFiles.Progress)<90));
```

Intent of the code is to take the highest frame number from one table, and replace the current frame number in another table with it, on entries under 90% completion. A select query returns the Max fine, but doing an update throws the error:

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'CurRecord' as part of an aggregate function."

Help with this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See whether a `DMax` expression (see [DMin, DMax Functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dmin-dmax-functions-HA001228826.aspx)) gets what you need from `dbo_tblStats` ... ask for the max `stopframe` where `Video` matches the current `FileName` value.

Assuming `Video` and `FileName` are both text data type, try this query.

```sql
UPDATE tblFiles
SET CurRecord =
        DMax(
            "stopframe",
            "dbo_tblStats",
            "Video='" & FileName & "'"
            )
WHERE Progress<90;
```